# Weinre and console.time()

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, weinre

I'm using weinre to see console from Sencha Touch application running on iPhone Simulator.

console.log() works correctly, and I can see it in weinre console, but
console.time('a') and console.timeEnd('a') doesn't working at all. Why?

I compile Sencha Touch application with Sencha Cmd, not with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality [never got added to weinre](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre/blob/master/weinre.web/modules/weinre/target/Console.coffee#L152).

Feel free to send a pull request!